# How to correctly discard old backups?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2014, ssis

I have an *Execute SQL Task* in my SSIS control flow that's backing up a number of databases before it proceeds to run the overnight ETL:

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'G:\Backups\DQ'
GO
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'G:\Backups\master'
GO
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'G:\Backups\Metadata'
GO
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'G:\Backups\NDS'
GO
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'G:\Backups\Staging'
GO
BACKUP DATABASE [DQ] TO  DISK = N'G:\Backups\DQ\DQ.bak' WITH  RETAINDAYS = 3, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'DQ', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
BACKUP DATABASE [master] TO  DISK = N'G:\Backups\master\master.bak' WITH  RETAINDAYS = 3, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'master', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
BACKUP DATABASE [Metadata] TO  DISK = N'G:\Backups\Metadata\Metadata.bak' WITH  RETAINDAYS = 3, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Metadata', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
BACKUP DATABASE [NDS] TO  DISK = N'G:\Backups\NDS\NDS.bak' WITH  RETAINDAYS = 3, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'NDS', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
BACKUP DATABASE [Staging] TO  DISK = N'G:\Backups\Staging\Staging.bak' WITH  RETAINDAYS = 3, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Staging', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

**The intent** is to only retain 3 days, and discard anything older.

**The problem** is that the .bak files just keep growing and growing for a week or two, until the G drive fills up and the *Execute SQL Task* fails, which aborts the overnight ETL.

It seems the .bak is apparently *not* discarding old backups; looks like I could go back all the way to the last time I deleted all the backups to free some disk space on that G drive:

[image: "restore to" dialog showing full db backups going back over a whole week]

**The question** is simple: it looks like my *Execute SQL Task* is doing it wrong. How do I fix it? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to switch to using a backup statement of:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Dbname] TO DISK = <Path> + <BackupName> WITH INIT
```

Build your `BackupName` using a variable that includes maybe the package runtime. Convert that timestamp to just something like `yyyymmddm` where you full backup file name comes out to something like: `DatabaseName_FULL_2015122205.bak`

You could then just add a process task in your package to execute a PowerShell command to delete files older than 3 days. Your process could be:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Get-ChildItem $BackupDirectory -Include *.bak -Recurse | where {$_.LastWriteTime -le ( (Get-Date).AddDays(-3) )| Remove-Item -force"
```

Answer (score 5):

My best recommendation for you is to use already applauded [backup solution from Ola](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html)

> CleanupTime
>
> Specify the time, in hours, after which the backup files are deleted. If no time is specified, then no backup files are deleted.

I normally, use `backup database ... with init` and then delete the backup files older than X days.

Ola's solution is a one stop solution and its very flexible, so you can tune it as per your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you will have to look elsewhere than in the BACKUP command to do what you are after in a automagical way.

Script it or use a 3rd party tool such as SQLSafe or RedGate SQL Backup.

If you read this short rant called
[Backup and the evil RETAINDAYS option](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2012/07/08/backup-and-the-evil-retaindays-option.aspx) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905101219/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2012/07/08/backup-and-the-evil-retaindays-option.aspx))
you will see that is actually just sets some expire flag that will throw errors if you try to backup using INIT.